# AJAX Data not Posting to View in Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I've implemented a basic checkout wherein a user may select a shipping address from a list of addresses via the 'address' class. It works on the server side, but I would like to use AJAX to avoid having the page refresh with each selection. The code is not posting any data, however. What am I doing wrong?

views.py

```
def pick_address(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    checkout = Checkout.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('checkout'))
    checkout.shipping_address = ShippingAddress.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('address'))
    checkout.save()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

pick_address.js

```
<script>
    $('.address').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'pick-address' %}',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
                checkout: {{ checkout.pk }},
                address: {{ address.pk }},
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data['success']) {
                    alert('success!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the slim version of jQuery, which does not support AJAX. The code was otherwise (mostly) correct.

Answer (score 1):

In **views.py**

```
def pick_address(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        checkout = Checkout.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('checkout'))
        checkout.shipping_address = ShippingAddress.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('address'))
        checkout.save()
        ctx={'success':True}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx),content_type='application/json')
```

in **pick_address.js**

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert('success!');
                }
            }
```